# Spawning Threads In Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, thread-safety

I have a web application that has to send requests to a database to retrieve data from. The annoying thing is that this database doesn't allow it to send the entirety of the of database (legacy design that I have no control over) so I have to send requests for all the entries... I was able to implement a solution by using parallel streams and spawning threads WITHIN the parallel stream. By doing so, I was able to reduce the time from 5 minutes to a solid 1 minute. But, I have yet to deploy this to the actual Tomcat server and before that I wanted to confirm if my solution wouldn't cause any thread-safety issues that I have read about; Majority of which are discussed 7 or 8 years ago....

This is an example template of what I am doing:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            ...
            ...
            Set<String> otherSet = new HashSet<String>();
            Set<String> set = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<String>());

            try {
                otherSet.parallelStream().forEach(e -> {
                    // Sends a request to retrieve from one table from
                    Thread t1 = new Thread(
                            new Runnable1(String x, String y, Set<String> set) {
                            // send a request to database and store in "set"  
                            });
                    // Sends a request to retrieve from another table from the database
                    Thread t2 = new Thread(
                            new Runnable2(String z, String k, Set<String> set) {
                            // send a request to database and store in "set"
                            });
                    t1.start();
                    t2.start();

                    try {
                        t1.join();
                        t2.join();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  } catch (Exception e) { }
                    ...
                    response.write(toJSONFormat(set));
}
```

Also, what are your thoughts on using:

System.setProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism", "XX");

I was able to reduce the time by another 10 seconds by setting XX to 10. And I am not exactly sure on the hardware specs the server is running on and it could have a lot more threads...

Comment: First time posting, so formatting the code was a struggle and I apologize if there are any compiling or formatting issues. I swear its correct and formatted better in my IDE...

Comment: [Parallel Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html) already use `ForkJoinPool` (pool of `Thread`s) behind the scenes to execute the tasks in parallel. You should not need to create and run `Thread`s. Are you using each element `e`? Why is `set` synchronized? What do you do with it?

Comment: I am using each element e to execute two requests in parallel (i.e sending a request to a database to retrieve two different types of data), this takes quite a bit of time and the reason for using parallel streams. "set" is synchronized because both of these threads that I created will be adding to it and I didn't want any data races to occur. As for what I do with it, I generate a report with it after I have retrieved all the data I needed from the database.